# Creating custom field with Display Suite and Profile 2

Tags: 7, entities, users, display-suite

I am trying to use Display Suite (newest version) to format the profile page for users. I am using the Profile2 module and the default main-profile type. I have the user's full name (not username) split into the fields for first, middle, and last. I am trying to create a custom field to combine these three fields as the full name.

I am trying to create a code field but I don't know what variable or replacement pattern to use. There is nothing in the list of available tokens. I have tried php using $content and $entity and get undefined variable errors.

How can I create a custom field in Display Suite to combine these three fields from a Profile2 entity?

Comment: Have you used token In code field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enough trial and error and I finally figured it out. I ended up using Display Suite Code as the text format, but writing php code in the field code box.

And to grab the first name the code was: `$entity->field_first_name['und'][0]['safe_value']`.

Comment: Great that you found a solution. You can accept your own answer so that others looking for the same solution can see quickly that there is a likely working solution. Another approach _might_ be to research applying [computed_field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module perhaps along with [field_token_value](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_token_value) that uses tokens (for providing other fields as variables) I haven't tried my suggestion, but thought I'd share as it looks worth exploring. These modules also have Drupal 8 versions as well as for 7.